# Sales Emails going via wrong email address magento 2.2.x

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, email, order-email, magento2.2.4

I have setup email address in sales representative but getting sales email from

> apache@domainname

So where I need to fix this issue? Can anyone let me know?

Other emails except sales are working fine.

Comment: Please check my ans, as I had same issue before and I have solved it.

Comment: Okay, I am trying.

Comment: ok please let me know if anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Source: https://github.com/sashas777/bug-from-email
>
> Issue on Magento's GitHub Repo: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952

Please check following steps to resolve this issue.

Create your custom module to rewrite core files

In your **/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml** add following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" />
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

In your **/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

In your **Vendor/Module/Rewrite/Framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Framework\Mail\Template;
class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    /**
     * @param $from
     * @param $store
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException
     */
    public function setFromByStore($from, $store)
    {
        $result = $this->_senderResolver->resolve($from, $store);
        $this->message->setFrom($result['email'], $result['name']);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

In your **Vendor/Module/Rewrite/Sales/Model/Order/Email/SenderBuilder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Sales\Model\Order\Email;
class SenderBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder
{
    /**
     * Configure email template
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureEmailTemplate()
    {
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->templateContainer->getTemplateId());
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateOptions($this->templateContainer->getTemplateOptions());
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateVars($this->templateContainer->getTemplateVars());
        /*Send From Email Issue #Dev110*/
        $this->transportBuilder->setFromByStore(
            $this->identityContainer->getEmailIdentity(),
            $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getId()
        );
        /*Send From Email Issue #Dev110*/
//        $this->transportBuilderByStore->setFromByStore(
//            $this->identityContainer->getEmailIdentity(),
//            $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getId()
//        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect...this is working fine for me. thank you