# Magento 2 displaying HOST name in sales email only

Tags: magento2, email-templates, hosting, name

`Magento 2` website Sales emails are showing `hostname` to customer i.e Apache.

Recently we have upgraded Magento version to `2.2.5` but initially, it was working fine before the upgrade.

Any suggestion?

Comment: i guess that maybe you have using some SMTP extension which is currently  not working

Comment: I don't think it is the issue because for contact and query forms , create account, forgot password etc it is working fine properly showing respective headings

Comment: Please check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241390/sales-emails-going-via-wrong-email-address-magento-2-2-x/241395#241395