# Email not sending magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, email, transaction

I sending email from one custom module so everything is working fine but If I change from , I am not getting emails.

```
 public function beforeSendMessage(\Magento\Email\Model\Transport $subject)    {
    $message = $subject->getMessage();
    $message->setFrom(array('email' => 'someemail@email.com', 'name' => 'SenderName'));`

}
```

I tried [Sales Emails going via wrong email address magento 2.2.x](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241390/sales-emails-going-via-wrong-email-address-magento-2-2-x) but doesnt help

Comment: can you send mails with plain PHP? you should verify this first

Comment: can you provide a little context to the method beforeSendMessage? that snippet can't work because `$message` is not defined

Comment: updated question

Comment: am getting problem with just setFrom method, everything else is working

Comment: OK, I guess that's a plugin before the `sendMesage` method. You might get a problem if there is an attempt to set the from header twice - but that should throw an exception from Zend_Mail class. You can try `$message->clearFrom()` before

Comment: what can I do in this condition

Comment: already tried that but doesnt work

Comment: Do you get an exception? First I would try to see if that's the problem and if yes it's most likely that the `sendMessage` method sets the From header too

Comment: I tried to catch exception but get nothing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of array passing string will solve the probelm

```
 public function beforeSendMessage(\Magento\Email\Model\Transport $subject)    {
        $message = $subject->getMessage();
        $message->clearFrom();
        $message->setFrom('someemail@email.com',);

    }
```